# Conjugate of integral of holomorphic funtion

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Let $\gamma \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a piecewise differentiable curve and let $\overline{\gamma}$ be the image of $\gamma$ under the conjugation map $\sigma(z) := \overline{z}$ Show that
> $$\overline{\int_\gamma f(z) \, dz} = \int_{\overline{\gamma}} \overline{f(\overline{z})}\, dz$$
> and show that if $\gamma$ defines the positively oriented united circle, then
> $$\overline{\int_{|z| = 1} f(z) \, dz} = - \int_{{|z| = 1}} \overline{f(\overline{z})}\, \frac{dz}{z^2}$$

My attempt: I have tried showing the difference is zero, where
$$\int_{\overline{\gamma}} \overline{f(\overline{z})}\, dz - \overline{\int_\gamma f(z) \, dz} = \int_{\sigma(\gamma)} \sigma(f(\sigma(z))\, dz - \overline{\int_\gamma f(z)\, dz}$$
However, I am not sure how to convert the integral over $\gamma$ instead of $\sigma(\gamma)$. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: The first part has already been asked and answered: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1536269/42969 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Coverline%7B%5Cint_%5Cgamma%20f(z)%20%5C%2C%20dz%7D%20%3D%20%5Cint_%7B%5Coverline%7B%5Cgamma%7D%7D%20%5Coverline%7Bf(%5Coverline%7Bz%7D)%7D%5C%2C%20dz%24) – can we close this as a duplicate?

Comment: @MartinR thank you. I am not sure how to close a question.